# How can I change my Right Ctrl Key to act as a backslash?

Tags: wayland, xmodmap, shortcut-keys

I wanted to be able to change my Right Control key to be backslash. I know that this is possible with xmodmap, however I couldn't make ubuntu run it on startup even if I put it in `.xinitrc` or `.Xmodmap` (this is probably because my default ubuntu 20.04 installation is running wayland). Previously, I wanted to swap my control and caps lock key and I did this by using gnome-tweaks, however I do not know how I can turn the right control key into  backslash using gnome-tweaks.